# TypeInitialization Exception in C#

Tags: c#

I've a simple implementation of a finite state machine, based on the information of a local `.csv` file:

The `TransitionTable.csv` is as simple as below:

```
q_src,eve,q_dst
q0,sig1,q1
q1,sig2,q2
```

Here is my main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BacktrackingPathFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<string[]> transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"TransitionTable.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            State q0 = new State("q0");
            Event e1 = new Event("sig1"); 
            PathFinder pf = new PathFinder();
            State s = pf.FindDestination(q0, e1, transitions);
            Console.WriteLine(s.ID);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And `PathFinder.cs` is defined as the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BacktrackingPathFinder
{
    public class PathFinder
    {
        public PathFinder()
        {

        }

        public State FindDestination(State q0, Event s0, IEnumerable<string[]> transitions)
        {
            var newq = from t in transitions
                       where t[0] == q0.ID && t[1] == s0.ID
                       select t[2];
            return new State(newq.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

According to my `.csv` file, the output should have been `q1`, but the following exception is thrown and I can't figure it out:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'BacktrackingPathFinder.Program' threw an exception.

Update:

I did as @Poke said:

```
class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string[]> transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"TransitionTable.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));
            State q0 = new State("q0");
            Event e1 = new Event("sig1"); 
            PathFinder pf = new PathFinder();
            State s = pf.FindDestination(q0, e1, transitions);
            Console.WriteLine(s.ID);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The exception is not resolved, and a new `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.
The `.csv` file is located as the project directory:
[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn’t be reading a file as part of the static constructor (i.e. don’t assign the `transitions` statically, but set the value from within the `Main`)

Comment: Your `PathFinder` type is not relevant here. The exception is thrown when the type initializer for `Program` runs (so *before* `Main` runs). The exception usually means that there was an exception while the type was being set up. In this case, determining the value for `transitions` failed. Possible guess: File was not found. – Look in the `InnerException` using the debugger for more information, or move the initialization into the `Main`.

Comment: @poke: I applied the change as you said; but the error is still the same plus a new one: `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Then you have your solution: `TransitionTable.csv` cannot be found. It needs to be next to the executable, but apparently isn’t there.

Comment: @poke: thanks... I put the file in debug file and the error is disappreared.

Comment: I think it's the same error in the end. Since you initialize the Program class with the reading of the file and this is failing, you get the typeinitialization exception. 
Try different things for the path of your file (including relative or full path just as a test).

Comment: @Etienne thanks for your help.